# Set two different onKeyListener to the same view - Android

Tags: android, events, keylistener

How can i set 2 onKeyListener to the same view.

For ex if I have a EditText et, I want

et.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener1);

et.setOnKeyListener(onKeyListener2);

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: Why do you need to have two OnKeyListeners ?

Comment: I'd add a TextWatcher to the EditText and then you can react to ALL keys and do anything only if the character (that you receive by parameter) is the one you want to react to.

Comment: I have a common key listener for all edit text, however there are some extra features that has to be implemented in 1 of the edit text. I dont want to reinvent the wheel and make a new listener, with same features (with some extra features). That's why the thought of having the extra features in separate listener.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't set two OnKeyListeners to the same EditText.

Now, I'm not exactly sure what the additional features are in your special EditText, but maybe you can implement View.OnKeyListener to achieve what you want:

```
public class CommonOnKeyListener implements View.OnKeyListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        /*
         *  Here, insert the code that is common to all your EditTexts
         */
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can define a second OnKeyListener that extends CommonKeyListener, and does some additional work for your particular EditText:

```
public class CustomOnKeyListener extends CommonOnKeyListener{
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        /* Make a call to the parent class's onKey method 
         * so you can reuse the functionality in your CommonOnKeyListener 
         */

        boolean result = super.onKey(v, keyCode, event);

        /*
         *  Your additional code goes here (e.g. for your special EditText)
         */

        return false;
    }
}
```

Now, all your EditTexts can use the CommonOnKeyListener, and you can set the CustomOnKeyListener to your special EditText:

```
View.OnKeyListener listener1 = new CommonOnKeyListener();
View.OnKeyListener listener2 = new CustomOnKeyListener();

// Set the key listeners to the appropriate EditTexts

yourEditText1.setOnKeyListener(listener1);
yourEditText2.setOnKeyListener(listener1);
yourSpecialEditText.setOnKeyListner(listener2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really... It's a set method and not add. You can try to send something out of your keylistener with a callback or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Not really but, you can try this,
write different 3 methods for what you need to do onClicks,

```
public void onclick1 (){
 // your code
}

public void onclick2 (){
 // your code
}

public void onclickMain (View v){
 // your code
}
```

use oncclickMain as your onclick event on XML part like this

```
android:onclick="onclickMain"
```

then on onclickMain you can use if condition to select what is the thing that you need to trigger.

I hope this works,